# Vuejs v-if statement adding property

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to display details depending on availability, I'm trying to add a computed property for the day of the week in the v-if statement. I've tried different ways and concatenating but can't seem to get it to work, I'm using firebase but recreated the code below.

```
<template>
  <div>  
    <h2>Practitioners Available for {{ getDayOfTheWeek }}</h2>
    <div v-for='prac in practitioners'>
      <div v-if='prac.availability.getDayOfTheWeek'> 
         // Display details
         {{ prac.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>                 
export default {                  
  data () 
    return {             
      practitioners: {    
        0: {             
          name: 'Matt',  
          availability: {
            sunday: true,
            monday: true,
            tuesday: true,
            wednesday: true,
            thursday: true,
            friday: true,
            saturday: true
          }
        } 
      }  
    }  
  },

  computed: {            
    getDayOfTheWeek: function () {  
      var date = new Date()
      var day = date.getDay()
      var daysOfTheWeek = [
        'sunday',
        'monday',
        'tuesday',
        'wednesday',
        'thursday',
        'friday',
        'saturday'
      ]
      return daysOfTheWeek[day]
    }
  }                                                                                                                                    
}
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `v-if="prac.availability.getDayOfTheWeek"` use `v-if="prac.availability[getDayOfTheWeek]"`.

Your availability object doesn't have `getDayOfTheWeek` property, `v-if="prac.availability.getDayOfTheWeek"` is equivalent of `v-if="prac.availability['getDayOfTheWeek']"`.